# insert assembled var to Unix time format in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a variable called `$eventTimeDate` which assemble the date Y-M-D and the time, the current output of this var is `2012-05-31 21:00:00` , i store this var in my mysql database already, then i select this value by using `SELECT UNIX_TIME() AS time`

what i need is to convert this output to this format `2332422323` like `unix` before i inserted to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strtotime($eventTimeDate)
See: [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

try with UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function

```
jcho360> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                            1196436619 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you want to converted again use this

```
jcho360> select from_unixtime(1196436619);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1196436619) |
+---------------------------+
| 2007-11-30 10:30:19       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks but i am looking for a method to convert it in php not mysql .. :)

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes ohh php have its own functions too, but mysql should be faster that php doing that, just to know ;)